# Join two tables using like predicate with character '_' in values and it is taking as wildcard character

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have two table

Table_A

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hisa |
| 2 | hipa |
| 3 | his_ |
| 4 | hip_ |

Table_B:

| pattern |
| --- |
| is_ |
| ip_ |
| ip_ |
| is_ |

```
select *
from Table_A A
inner join Table_B B
    on A.name like '%'+B.pattern+'%'
```

by using this ip_, is_ is matching with ipa and isa as '_' is acting as a wild card

```
select *
from Table_A A
inner join Table_B B
    on A.name like '%'+B.pattern ESCAPE '\'+'%'
```

I am getting error for this as I cannot use escape character in like predicate.

My expected output is `hip_` should match with  any text preceding and followed `ip_` followed by any characters.

Comment: You should remove the leading `%` from your `LIKE` pattern because that will allow arbitrary text _before_ the "ip_" string - unless that's intentional?

Comment: The [`like` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) explains clearly how to do that.

Comment: Why don't you replace underscore in your table first then join the table? After that, you can replace underscore back again.

Comment: Special characters in pattern needs to be escaped. If it is only underscores then `LIKE '%' + REPLACE(pattern, '_', '[_]') + '%'`

Comment: *"I am getting error for this as I cannot use escape character in like predicate."* `ESCAPE` goes after the *entire* clause not in the middle of it: `LIKE '%' + B.pattern + '%' ESCAPE '\'`